# Slow fade effect when wrapped in <form runat=server>

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I am trying to use following beautiful demo as my masterpage in asp.net webform project:
[secondary-expandable-navigation](http://codyhouse.co/demo/secondary-expandable-navigation/index.html#0).

Downloaded sample works fine, even when copied and pasted in masterpage without any server-side form tag, the transition runs very smooth (I mean the drawer effect from right to left).

The only thing I added to master page is a form element right after opening body tag and closing it before /body tag. Now the transition does not work as before and the main content eases faster than it should.

I am not good at UI, may be somebody can point me my mistake(s). Meanwhile I need to wrap both navigation and content sections in form tag to place my server-side controls.

**Note:** To see the mentioned effect, just click on the top right "menu" button to open the menu, Then click it again to close the menu.

Thanks

**Edit:**
To recreate the problem please do the following steps:

First download the sample from the [link](http://codyhouse.co/demo/secondary-expandable-navigation/index.html#0).

Then create a web form application project in visual studio and add a masterpage with the following code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->      
    <title>Secondary Expandable Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <header>
        <a id="cd-logo" href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Homepage"></a>
        <nav id="cd-top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#0">Tour</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a id="cd-menu-trigger" href="#0"><span class="cd-menu-text">Menu</span><span class="cd-menu-icon"></span></a>
    </header>
    <main class="cd-main-content">
        <!-- put your content here -->
    </main> <!-- cd-main-content -->
    <nav id="cd-lateral-nav">
        <ul class="cd-navigation">
            <li class="item-has-children">
                <a href="#0">Services</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#0">Brand</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">Web Apps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">Mobile Apps</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> <!-- item-has-children -->
                <a href="#0">Stockists</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#0">London</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">New York</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">Milan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">Paris</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> <!-- item-has-children -->
        </ul> <!-- cd-navigation -->
    </nav>
    </form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var $lateral_menu_trigger = $('#cd-menu-trigger'),
            $content_wrapper = $('.cd-main-content'),
            $navigation = $('header');

        //open-close lateral menu clicking on the menu icon
        $lateral_menu_trigger.on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $lateral_menu_trigger.toggleClass('is-clicked');
            $navigation.toggleClass('lateral-menu-is-open');
            $content_wrapper.toggleClass('lateral-menu-is-open').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function () {
                // firefox transitions break when parent overflow is changed, so we need to wait for the end of the trasition to give the body an overflow hidden
                $('body').toggleClass('overflow-hidden');
            });
            $('#cd-lateral-nav').toggleClass('lateral-menu-is-open');

            //check if transitions are not supported - i.e. in IE9
            if ($('html').hasClass('no-csstransitions')) {
                $('body').toggleClass('overflow-hidden');
            }
        });

        //close lateral menu clicking outside the menu itself
        $content_wrapper.on('click', function (event) {
            if (!$(event.target).is('#cd-menu-trigger, #cd-menu-trigger span')) {
                $lateral_menu_trigger.removeClass('is-clicked');
                $navigation.removeClass('lateral-menu-is-open');
                $content_wrapper.removeClass('lateral-menu-is-open').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function () {
                    $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
                });
                $('#cd-lateral-nav').removeClass('lateral-menu-is-open');
                //check if transitions are not supported
                if ($('html').hasClass('no-csstransitions')) {
                    $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
                }

            }
        });

        //open (or close) submenu items in the lateral menu. Close all the other open submenu items.
        $('.item-has-children').children('a').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-open').next('.sub-menu').slideToggle(200).end().parent('.item-has-children').siblings('.item-has-children').children('a').removeClass('submenu-open').next('.sub-menu').slideUp(200);
        });
    });
</script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

Then you need to add two CSS files, use the downloaded sample and copy the css folder to the project (since the "style.css" has 407 lines, I'd rather not to copy it here for clarity).

Now you should create a webform with masterpage and see the output in the browser; There is a lag when opening and closing the panel. To remove the lag, you may delete the `<form id="frmMain" runat="server">` and `</form>` from the code and the sample will run fine. My question is why this lagging occurs when I wrap everything in a `<form runat="server">` tag?

Comment: It is not clear on the linked page which "drawer effect" you are talking about. What do I need to do to see the issue you are trying to describe?

Comment: I updated the link to point to the demo section and also put a note for you in the question.

Comment: I really can't understand down-voting without any comment. It is a poor design of stackoverflow!

Comment: The page you linked does not look like it has any problems. Can you provide a sample of code (like a jsfiddle, or code snippet here in your question) that will demonstrate the undesired behavior?

Comment: Since I don't know how to create a masterpager with <form runat="server"> in a fiddle, I copied the main part here with step by step description.